# How to display elements inside a section in html within the section in the webpage?

Tags: html, css

I have some elements within a section in a webpage. Here's my code. You just need to look at the section with `id="recent-blog-article"`. I am including more code because it might help people understand. In the CSS, the relevant portion is below the `/* Relevant Section */` comment.

```css
#welcome-heading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 158px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#introduction-heading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 198px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#wondering-heading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    width: 100%;
}

#headings-section a {
    color: #FF0000;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* Next Area */
#content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 135px;
    top: 317px;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 876px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 60px;
    grid-column-gap: 60px;
    grid-template-areas: "content-a content-b content-c"
                         "content-d content-e content-f";
    margin-bottom: 74px;
}

#content-a {
    grid-area: content-a;
}

#content-b {
    grid-area: content-b;
}

#content-c {
    grid-area: content-c;
}

#content-d {
    grid-area: content-d;
}

#content-e {
    grid-area: content-e;
}

#content-f {
    grid-area: content-f;
}

#content {
    text-align: center;
}

#content img {
    margin-bottom: 33px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
}

#content h4 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content-title-anchor {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #333333;
}

.button-anchor {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 27px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FF5A43;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/* Next Area */
/* Relevant Section */
#recent-blog-article {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1273px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 836px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #F4F8FA;
}

#recent-blog-article h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 135px;
    top: 1353px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333333;
}

#view-blog-anchor {
    position: absolute;
    left: 135px;
    top: 1395px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #E74225;
}

#recent-blog-article img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 calc((100% - 1048px) / 2);
    top: 1480px;
    width: 1048px;
    height: 405px;
}

#blog-article-link-anchor {
    position: absolute;
    left: 135px;
    top: 1910px;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333333;
}

#article-metadata, #article-metadata a {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #666666;
}

#article-metadata {
    position: absolute;
    left: 135px;
    top: 1951px;
    text-align: left;
}

#blog-article-introduction {
    position: absolute;
    left: 135px;
    top: 1994px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section id="headings-section">
        <h1 id="welcome-heading">Welcome to Icon Utopia!</h1>
        <h3 id="introduction-heading">Everything about <a href="free-icon-design-guide.html">iconography</a> and <a href="build-your-dribbble-audience.html">building your career</a> as a designer.</h3>
        <p id="wondering-heading">Wondering where to start?</p>
    </section>
    <section id="content">
        <div id="content-a">
            <a href="build-your-dribbble-audience.html"><img src="index/landing-page.jpg" alt="Guide to: Building your dribbble following."></a>
            <a class="content-title-anchor" href="build-your-dribbble-audience.html">Build Your Dribbble Audience</a>
            <h4>A Comprehensive Guide to Building your Dribbble following.</h4>
            <a class="button-anchor" href="build-your-dribbble-audience.html">Get a FREE Chapter!</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content-b">
            <a href="free-icon-design-guide.html"><img src="index/icon-design-guide2-1.jpg" alt="LEARN ICON DESIGN"></a>
            <a class="content-title-anchor" href="free-icon-design-guide.html">Free Icon Design Guide</a>
            <h4>Everything you need to know about icon design to get started.</h4>
            <a class="button-anchor" href="free-icon-design-guide.html">Learn Icon Design</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content-c">
            <a href="crafting-pixel-perfect-icons-the-right-way.html"><img src="index/pixel-perfect-icons.jpg" alt="CRAFTING PIXEL PERFECT ICONS"></a>
            <a class="content-title-anchor" href="crafting-pixel-perfect-icons-the-right-way.html">Pixel Perfect Course</a>
            <h4>Crafting Pixel Perfect Icons The Right Way - learn to create sharp-looking icons!</h4>
            <a class="button-anchor" href="crafting-pixel-perfect-icons-the-right-way.html">Check out the Course</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content-d">
            <a href="https://gumroad.com/l/ojcK"><img src="index/space-noise-brushes.jpg" alt="SPACE NOISE: PROCREATE BRUSH SET"></a>
            <a class="content-title-anchor" href="https://gumroad.com/l/ojcK">Space Noise Brushes</a>
            <h4>Procreate brushes that give your drawings fantastic textures</h4>
            <a class="button-anchor" href="https://gumroad.com/l/ojcK">Get Noise Brushes</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content-e">
            <a href="https://iconutopia.com/free-icons/"><img src="index/free-icons.jpg" alt="FREE ICONS"></a>
            <a class="content-title-anchor" href="https://iconutopia.com/free-icons/">Free Icons</a>
            <h4>Best FREE vector icons and icon sets for personal and commercial use</h4>
            <a class="button-anchor" href="https://iconutopia.com/free-icons/">Get Free Icons</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content-f">
            <a href="blog.html"><img src="index/icon-utopia-blog-2.jpg" alt="MY BLOG: ICON UTOPIA"></a>
            <a class="content-title-anchor" href="blog.html">Icon Utopia Blog</a>
            <h4>Blog about making a steady income and building a career as an icon designer.</h4>
            <a class="button-anchor" href="blog.html">Check out the Blog</a>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="recent-blog-article">
        <h1>Recent Blog Article:</h1>
        <a id="view-blog-anchor" href="blog.html">View Blog ></a>
        <img src="index/fries-hero.png" alt="french fries in a box icon">
        <a id="blog-article-link-anchor" href="https://iconutopia.com/best-icons-of-the-month-april-2020/">Best Icons of the Month! (April 2020)</a>
        <p id="article-metadata">by <a href="https://iconutopia.com/author/admin/">Justas</a> | May 2, 2020 | <a href="https://iconutopia.com/category/inspiration/">Inspirations</a></p>
        <p id="blog-article-introduction">As I do every month, I collected the best icons to give you this essential pinch of inspiration and keep the fire inside of you burning. Take a peak into these different styles and unique approaches towards icon design! It’s always a great pleasure to discover them. I’m pretty sure that you will find some fantastic icon designers and icon sets amongst the ones I selected for you this time.</p>
    </section>
</main>
```

Here's the output. I've zoomed out.

[image]

As you can see, the section itself is completely empty, while the content I want to go inside of it is below it. I've checked the positions of the elements (using a chrome extension) that should be inside the section, and their `top` is larger than what I have specified in the CSS. I have tried different variations of `position` and other properties, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elements inside your `<section>` have `position: absolute;` in combination with `top` and `left` properties which is deadly for your style.
For instance the css for your `<h1>`.

```
position: absolute;
left: 135px;
top: 1353px;
```

This means that the headline is positioned **absolute** inside its parent and it has a *gap* of 1353px to the top of its parent. So `top: 0` would mean that the headline begins just inside its parent section (I guess that is what you want). So because of the things mentioned above, the section's children have all a big gap to its parent, that's because they aren't displayed inside.

I would recommend to remove your `position: absolute` properties for allmost all elements inside your `section`, replace them by `relative` (it depends, *where* a child exactly should be positioned). Also I recommend to use a flexbox (`display: flex;`) which makes the positioning easier. For spacing you can use `margin` and `padding` properties.

```css
.section-2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 64px;
    background: red;
    color: #000;
}
.section-2 h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}

.section-2 span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}

.section-1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 64px;
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
}
.section-1 h1{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 16px;
}

.section-1 span{
    position: relative;;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-1">
   <h1>RELATIVE POSITIONED </h1>
   <span>RELATIVE POSITIONED TEXT</span>
</section>

<section class="section-2">
   <h1>ABSOLUTE POSITIONED</h1>
   <span>ABSOLUTE POSITIONED TEXT</span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the image's CSS first try:

```css
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
```

This will centralize the image inside the div. Still having the problem... Try changing the width of the entire containing div to be fixed and not 100%.

```css
width: 1080px;
```

or whatever you prefer...

Comment: Make sure you use the width in absolute units not relative to the screen size... Like px,in,cm

Comment: The image is already centered. And I just tried setting the width in pixels; it didn't work.

Comment: No the property that will set the image inside that section is display inline-block and margin: auto will center it... In case, the image didn't set in width then try giving it a pixeled width.